# Making Images in Collection Binary Based on Threshold

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, modis

I am trying to make every image in a collection into a binary image based on whether it's band's pixel value is higher or lower than a certain threshold. For instance, if an image's pixel in a selected band is above 450 I want it's value to be reassigned to 1, but if it is below 450 I want it to equal zero. The code I wrote is able to make all pixels below 450 equal to 0, but I can't get it to do the conversion to a pixel value of 1 for the greater than portion...

Here is the code I wrote:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1cc75cf12cd5891bb0da252344018f01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out using the .where function. Here is the example solution if anyone wants it: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e0f5c4999e9dc62c01b3f80d74a55adf